# Symfony Doctrine - OrderBy after query

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.8

I'd like to order only the result of the previous main query.

I want the top 10 most viewed articles then ordered it by "addedAt date" DESC.

I'm aware of functions such as **orderBy** or even **addOrderBy** but it's not what I need here or I'm not implementing it correctly.

Example to get the top 2 on 5 articles :

- name : a || views : **100** || addedAt : **10**/04/2017
- name : b || views : 10 || addedAt : 17/04/2017
- name : c || views : 50  || addedAt : 15/04/2017
- name : d || views : 25  || addedAt : 12/04/2017
- name : e || views : **200**  || addedAt : **05**/04/2017

I extract first the most views :

1. Article e
2. Article a

And then orderedIt by addedAt date DESC (most recent) :

1. Article a
2. Article e

My query :

```
public function findMostViewed($limit=10, $asArray=false)
{
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('n')
            ->orderBy('n.nbViews', 'DESC')
            //->addOrderBy('n.addedAt', 'DESC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->setMaxResults($limit);

        return ($asArray) ? $qb->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY) : $qb->getResult();
}
```

If I knew how to do a preSelectQuery it would have probably solve the problem ...

I thought to an SQL query :

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE id IN(SELECT id FROM News ORDER BY nbViews DESC LIMIT 10)
ORDER BY addedAt DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on **Veve**'s answer, I changed the WHERE IN condition and managed to make it work.

```
public function findMostViewed($limit=10, $asArray=false)
{
        $subqb = $this->createQueryBuilder('nn')
            ->orderBy('nn.nbViews', 'DESC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->setMaxResults($limit);

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('n')
            ->where('n.id IN (:ids)')
            ->setParameter('ids', array_values($subqb->getResult()))
            ->orderBy('n.addedAt', 'DESC')
            ->getQuery();

        return ($asArray) ? $qb->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY) : $qb->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a subquery and use it in your main query:

```
public function findMostViewed($limit=10, $asArray=false)
{
        $subqb = $this->createQueryBuilder('nn')
            ->orderBy('nn.nbViews', 'DESC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->setMaxResults($limit);

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('n')
            ->where($qb->expr()->in('n.id', $subqb->getDQL())
            ->orderBy('n.addedAt', 'DESC')
            ->getQuery();

        return ($asArray) ? $qb->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY) : $qb->getResult();
}
```

Note the use of `nn` instead of `n` in the subquery.

Comment: Your code didn't work. Attempted to call an undefined method named "getResult" of class "Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder". The Where In condition  must be reason. Even so, I solved it myself on your example and changing the IN condition. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you use first order by 'n.addedAt', and then 'n.nbViews', like this:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('n')
            ->orderBy('n.addedAt', 'DESC')
            ->addOrderBy('n.nbViews', 'DESC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->setMaxResults($limit);
```

Comment: No it's not what I want. With this, I'd get the most recent records and the second orderBy would not even work if there are no record with an "addedAt" similar.

Answer (score 0):

It is work too.
If you add **->setFirstResult( '1' )** to the code's **Israel Rodriguez Sanchez** works

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('n')
->orderBy('n.addedAt', 'DESC')
->addOrderBy('n.nbViews', 'DESC')
->getQuery()
->setFirstResult( '1' )
->setMaxResults($limit);
```